# Regular expression

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I need to write a mod_rewrite rule that would match the following string:

```
/modules/users/users/ae/ghwjzL9D2qpnPqv3FRY3JTZ48N
```

the only constant part of the string is `/ae/`.

I need a regular expression to catch a part of the string before `/ae/` and after `/ae/` and redirect appropriately.

so something like this

url entered: `/modules/users/users/ae/ghwjzL9D2qpnPqv3FRY3JTZ48N`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\/])+\/ae\/([a-zA-z0-9])* $1/file.php?id=$2
```

url processed: `/modules/users/users/file.php?id=$2`

so far im able to catch the url but can't get the right variables

Comment: You probably want to put the `*` right after the `]`, before the `)`; i.e., ```…0-9]*)```.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right, I had to adjust it just a tiny bit:

```
^([a-zA-z0-9\/]+)\/ae\/([a-zA-z0-9]*)
```

Comment: The reason of course is that you want to first match a series of characters and _then_ use the entire series as a single group. (You don't want many groups consisting of a single character each!) Therefore the `(…)` grouping parens must surround the _whole_ matcher that you want to put in the variable.